# Strange broken var_dump loop ends with ... string (#)

Tags: php, string, loops, character, var-dump

```
   &nbsp;$nbsp;&nbs"...
string(8) "result 2"
```

This is part of the result from a `var_dumped` `$result` generated from fetched sql query.

I simply wonder what is the specific meaning of "`...`" when it suppose to keep generating more `$nbsp;` and one more `$nbsp;` after and a name string (i.e. "`David`"), while it just shows "`...`" instead. The whole loops seems stuck right there.

I did not see any special character that is inside the name itself, so I don't see why php can not parse the name string.

I can not find trouble within logic of the code nor in the database table.

I think this "`...`" and the missing `p;`in expected result could be the key hint of the issue.

[image]

Var_dumped result was for a list item (i.e. `<ul><li>$nbsp;$nbsp;$nbsp;MrAdam<li></ul>`
Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: This `"..."` probably mean it has more content to show but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: @ Rahil Wazir thanks for the hint! and I particularly do not understand, what scenarios are causing this ... to happen, specifically, for my case, its inside a list.

Comment: Could you show the full debug response?

Comment: I just updated the question with screnshot!

Comment: The only response `var_dump` is spitting is `string(8) "result 2"` the `&nbsp;...` text is not part of the `var_dump` output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rahil, for following up on the question, the question you asked bring me attention to something I did not pay attention of.

I should not have used `var_dump`. `echo()` is the one I should have used.

Resolved!

Thanks!